# How to avoid pagebreak using input?

Tags: formatting, input, include

I'm just starting to use TeX, and I'm having a lot of trouble with it, which is why I'm asking.

I am creating a solution of Lang Algebra for my personal collection. Since there are a lot of exercises, I think it is essential to save them in separate files, so I started to separate them and write them in TeX.

I know how to concatenate TeX files using input, but I'm getting unnecessary pagebreaks and would like some help.

I currently write my files this way:

```
Main
ㄴMain of Chapter 1
　ㄴChapter 1, section 1
　ㄴChapter 1, section 2
　ㄴChapter 1, section 3
...
```

And Main of Chapter 1 is just like this.

```
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\include{Ch01/ch01_1}
\include{Ch01/ch01_2}
\include{Ch01/ch01_3}
```

This is creating unnecessary page transitions like below. What can I do to fix this? Please let me know!

[image: This is what I want]
This is what I want.

[image: But This happens]
But it's outputting like this

Comment: use `\input`, `\include` forces page breaks